# Azure SQL Server cannot create database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to create a database in Azure SQL Server. However, when I try to create it, it prompts "Gen4 family is not available in this region" and cannot create the database. What is the problem?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create a Managed Instance. It can be created only in supported regions. To create a managed instance in a region that is currently not supported, you can send a support request via the Azure portal.

To know more about supported regions:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/global-infrastructure/services/?products=sql-database&regions=all

**Also Note:**
New Gen4 databases are no longer supported in the AustraliaEast region.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this same error when trying to create the DB via the GUI menu.  So I opened a query and entered CREATE DATABASE dbname and it worked without issue.

Strange since they both should have used the default options, there should really have been no difference.

Answer (score 2):

As Vijay Rajendiran said, if the region where your Azure SQL server in is not support Gen4 price tier, then you could not create the database.

To solve the problem, I have two suggestions:

1. create the database with other price tier except `Gen4 - General Purpose (GP_Gen4_1)`.
2. create the database with new SQL server, when we configure the database price tier, portal will show us if the price tier  is supported.

Hope this helps.